# Laravel | How to append parameter to URL when using Redirect::route and Redirect::back()?

Tags: laravel, redirect, query-string, laravel-5.4

My view provides links like `http://finance.dev/home/customer/6#tab_1_3` so that user a can directly navigate to a tab in the page using the link.

**In my routes I have :**

```
    Route::get('/home/customer/{id}',[
        'as' => 'home.customer',
        'uses' => 'CustomerController@show'
    ]);

    Route::get('/home/customer/{id}/{navigate}/{tab}',[
        'as' => 'home.customer.navigate',
        'uses' => 'CustomerController@navigate'
    ]);
```

**I am passing the required variables to route using:**

```
window.location.href = '/home/customer/'+id+'/'+navigate+'/'+tab;
```

**And my controller logic is :**

```
public function navigate($id, $navigate, $tab)
    {
        $user = customer::find($id);


        if($navigate == 'previous')
        {    
            // get previous user id
            $go = customer::where('id', '<', $user->id)->max('id');
        }
        elseif ($navigate == 'next') {
           // get next user id
            $go = customer::where('id', '>', $user->id)->min('id');
        }
        else{

            return \Redirect::back();
        }
        return \Redirect::route('home.customer', array('id' => $go));


    }
```

The above code successfully returns a URL like `http://finance.dev/home/customer/6`

Now I am trying to figure out how to define `\Redirect::route` and `\Redirect::back()` to return a URL like `http://finance.dev/home/customer/6#tab_1_3`

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = URL::route('home.customer', ['id' => $go])."#tab_1_6";

return \Redirect::to($url);
```

Reference [Link](https://laravel.io/forum/02-07-2014-how-to-append-hashtag-to-end-of-url-with-redirect)